# gcc on Lubuntu not working

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to use the `gcc` on `Lubuntu`.

I have done the following installs but get the message *"The program 'gcc' can be found in the following packages"*

`sudo apt-get install gcc`

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

What I am doing wrong, is there a way I can verify the gcc was correctly installed?

Comment: Type "gcc" and then press Tab two or three times. Does it auto-complete to anything else?

Comment: No there is no auto completion after gcc

Comment: When you installed those packages were there any errors signaling that the packages were not installed?

Comment: if you run those commands, what is the output? could you paste it here in text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet its not in your path variable

```
env | grep path
```

If that doesn't work you need to add the location of gcc to your path environment variable by the looks of it.

To find gcc try:

```
find . -name gcc
```

Then to add to path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/gcc
echo $PATH;
```

If that fails, try this guide it may be an issue with your calls to apt-get https://askubuntu.com/questions/240919/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-on-lubuntu-11-10

Comment: `find . -name gcc` doesnt return anything. I am assuming this is bad

Comment: maybe. What happens when you run `/usr/bin/gcc -v`

Comment: Yes it is definitely not there

Comment: Try this guide: http://askubuntu.com/questions/240919/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-on-lubuntu-11-10